# How do I find the author in a List containing who has written most books

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have a Book class which has the members titel and author.
I also have a List of books, and I want to return the author who has written most books (occurs most times in the list). It's in C#. Thanks!

Like this:

List of Book:

> Author - Titel
>
> author1 - Peter Pan
>
> author2 - The Shining
>
> author2 - IT
>
> author3 - Animal Farm

return author2.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is a common practice around here to post some code that you tried, even if it does not work. This lets others know that you are trying to learn something, not simply asking them to do your work.

Comment: so where is the question ???

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ

```
    internal class Book
    {
        public string Author;
        public string Title;
    }

    List<Book> listOfBooks = new List<Book>()
    {
        new Book() {Author = "author1", Title = "Peter Pan"},
        new Book() {Author = "author2", Title = "The Shining"},
        new Book() {Author = "author2", Title = "IT"},
        new Book() {Author = "author3", Title = "Animal Farm"},
    };

    var author = listOfBooks.GroupBy(x => x.Author)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
        .Take(1)
        .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: Hi, I've never worked with LINQ before, and I'm still not certain how to get author out as a string. author.ToString() will not give me the text I'm looking for.

Comment: you can do:  
string author = listOfBooks.GroupBy(x => x.Author)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .Take(1)
            .Select(g => g.Key).FirstOrDefault();